# Google analytics event tracking not showing accurate data?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I have a "Download" button on my webpage(page1). Onclick of this button, a downloadFile.php page(page2) opens and a zip file automatically downloads.
I want to track the onclick event in page1. So I have set up the Google analytics event tracking on click. The code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
 _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-1']);
 _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
 _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mydomain.com']);
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

 (function() {
   var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
   ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
 })();

</script>  

 <a  href="downloadFile.php" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'name1', 'Download', 'Download trial']);">Download</a>
```

I also store the user(USER_AGENT) info on page load. So I get the number of downloads.

The google analytics event data shows up but, the onclick event number and the download number do not match. That is, if on click event is 85, the download count that I have recorded is 700. That big difference. I feel that the analytics click event tracking is not accurate. Is this possible? Or have I made a mistake in setting up the tracking code?

Comment: See [Outbound Links](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1136920&topic=1136919&ctx=topic) You may have to add a `setTimeout` to record the event before the download page loads.

Comment: Thank you.. It works well with setting a time delay.